# Convexity of a bivariate function.

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I have a function is two variables, $f(x,y)$. $f$ is twice continuously differentiable and increasing in x and y. I want to say that in definition of $f$, $y$ takes the form $y^\alpha$ where $\alpha>1$. I had first written that $f$ is convex in $y$, which I now think is not the correct way to write it. For $f$ to be convex, I would have to check the Hessian. Also, can a bivariate function be convex in just one variable? How can I write this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convexity in individual components is not only well-defined, but is a common concept, particularly in optimisation. We would say $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ (or possibly $\Bbb{R} \cup \{\infty\})$ is convex in the first component if, for all $y \in \Bbb{R}$, the one-variable map $x \mapsto f(x, y)$ is convex.

As an inequality, this is equivalent to, for all $x_1, x_2, y \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, we have
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2, y) \le \lambda f(x_1, y) + (1 - \lambda)f(x_2, y).$$
If you prefer to think in terms of derivatives, assuming $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is convex in the first component if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is increasing in $x$. Or, if $f$ is twice differentiable, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \ge 0$.

Of course, these definitions/results generalise in the expected way for $f$ being convex in the second component. Additionally, they also generalise to functions of more variables as well.

There is even a term for a multivariate function that is convex in all of its components: a separately convex function. Note that this is a weaker condition than traditional convexity (often known in this context as joint convexity). For example, $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is separately convex (since $x \mapsto xy$ and $y \mapsto xy$ are both affine and hence convex), but it is not a (jointly) convex function.

Comment: Oh, and I'm really not sure what the phrase "$y$ takes the form $y^\alpha$ where $\alpha > 1$" actually means about $f$. It sounds like you might have something a little stronger than convexity in mind, but whatever it is, you should be able to apply it to just the second coordinate, by demanding it hold true for all maps of the form $y \mapsto f(x, y)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!